# Trouble reading from Memory Mapped File

Tags: c#, ipc, shared-memory

I am trying to implement a Memory Mapped File within my application (specifically a Windows Service), and then use a C# form to read from MMF the service writes to. Unfortunately i cannot seem to get the form to read anything from the MMF, more importantly it seems that the form never finds the MMF created by the Service. Below are code snippets that outline what im doing, can anyone see what I am doing wrong or be able to point me in a better direction?

Service :

```
private MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("AuditStream", 1024 * 1024);
private Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, "MyMutex");

byte[] msg = new byte[1];
var view = mmf.CreateViewStream(0, 1);
byte[] rmsg = new byte[1];

for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++)
{
     mutex.WaitOne();
     for (int j = 0; j < msg.Length; j++)
     {
          msg[j] = (byte)i;
     }

     view.Position = 0;
     view.Write(msg, 0, bufferSize);

     //the next 3 lines verify that i wrote to the mmf and can potentially read from it
     //These are just for testing
     view.Position = 0;
     view.Read(rmsg, 0, 1);
     Log.Error("Finished MMF", rmsg[0].ToString());

     mutex.ReleaseMutex();
 }
```

Form:

```
private MemoryMappedFile mmf;
private Mutex mutex;
Thread t = new Thread(MmfMonitor);
t.Start();

private void MmfMonitor()
    {

        byte[] message = new byte[1];
        while(!quit)
        {
            try
            {
                **mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("AuditStream");**
                mutex = Mutex.OpenExisting("MyMutex");
                var view = mmf.CreateViewStream(0, 1);

                mutex.WaitOne();
                view.Position = 0;
                view.Read(message, 0, 1);
                Invoke(new UpdateLabelCallback(UpdateLabel), message[0].ToString());
                mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            }catch(FileNotFoundException)
            {
                **//The AuditStream MMF is never found, and therefore doesnt every see the proper values**
            }
        }
    }
```

Additionally, while the service is 'Running', the MMF should always have a handle and shouldnt get collected by the garbage collector;

Comment: So, you *do* get the FileNotFoundException?

Comment: Is the form exe in the same directory as the service?  Sometimes service's default directory is c:\windows\system32  I would try specifying the full path of the file, not a relative path like "AuditStream"

Comment: What is the account under which the service is run?

Comment: @ Peter - Yes i get a FileNotFoundException, and no the form isnt in the same directory as the service since its a completely separate project. Since this is shared memory space and not a specific file there is no 'path' other than the name

Comment: @HABO, if it were a permissions issue, I would expect an access denied exception...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The service runs in a different session, the famous "session 0".  Windows objects live in a namespace that's associated with the session of the process, so your form can't see the object created in the session used by the service.

You must prepend `Global\` to the mmf name to create and access the object in the global namespace.

So in the service:

```
mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen(@"Global\AuditStream", ...)
```

and in the form:

```
mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting(@"Global\AuditStream");
```

Comment: Thank you that did it!, now i just have to wrestle with an Access denied error on that.

Comment: I want to add for any others who view this post, to not forget to do the same with your mutex( "Global") also, you most likely will come across an access issue once you can see the stream the following is a way to fix it, though it does leave it very 'open':

Comment: var security = new MemoryMappedFileSecurity();
    security.AddAccessRule(new AccessRule<MemoryMappedFileRights>("everyone", MemoryMappedFileRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
    mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen(@"Global\AmToteAuditStream", 1024 * 1024, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite, MemoryMappedFileOptions.DelayAllocatePages,security, HandleInheritability.Inheritable );

Comment: @Zholen Your last comment fixes the access denied exception?