# Memory Map reader cannot find Global Memory Mapped Object

Tags: c#, c++

I am writing a C# program which creates and writes to a memory mapped file. A C++ program (copy pasted from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/memory/creating-named-shared-memory)) opens the memory mapped file and reads the contents. However, the C++ program cannot find the memory mapped file.

I have set the object name to be global (i.e. "Global\MyMemoryMappedObject") and this is the name used for both programs for creating and opening as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547583/trouble-reading-from-memory-mapped-file) but this has not solved the issue.

Here is the C# code I wrote to create and write to the MMF

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{


    String _szName = "Global\\MyMemoryMappedObject";
    String _szMessage = "Testing";
    int _szSize = 64;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }

    private void InitMemoryMap()
    {
        using (MemoryMappedFile _mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew(_szName, _szSize, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWriteExecute))
        {
            using (MemoryMappedViewAccessor _accessor = _mmf.CreateViewAccessor(0, _szSize, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Write))
            {
                byte[] textBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_szMessage);
                _accessor.WriteArray(0, textBytes, 0, textBytes.Length);

                lblStatus.Text = "1";
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnMMap_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InitMemoryMap();
    }
}
```

I expected that the C++ program would be able to read the contents since it uses the same object handle and offset, but it simply cannot find the mmf object to begin with. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are seemingly opening and closing it (and releasing the resources).

```
using (MemoryMappedFile _mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew(...))
{

} // here you have just released all the resources
```

If you want to share this file with another process, then you will need to keep it open

Comment: Oh, ok I see. So if I wanted to keep it open, I could add an event handler inside the bracket? Or is there a proper way to do it?

Comment: @Hayden no you would probably not use a using statement, and close and dispose of `_mmf` at a different time

Comment: Ok thank you. I rewrote without using statements and it's working.